# Importing only specific XML parameters to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have been reading and reading on how to import xml into my SQL Server and I am so close.

The last issue I have is the xml file has hundreds of items in it. Some have a few additional parameters listed so the import errors out and won't load.

I only need like 5 of these parameters to pull in and can't figure out how to pull just those.

My code is here; it works if I just put one or two devices in the `testing.xml` file that have just these parameters. It doesn't work if a new parameter is in one of the devices.

I really only need `deviceId`, `deviceDescription` and `versionModelNumber` which are in ALL records.

```
INSERT INTO DeviceDB (publicDeviceRecordKey, publicVersionStatus, deviceRecordStatus, publicVersionNumber, publicVersionDate, deviceCommDistributionEndDate, deviceCommDistributionStatus, deviceId, deviceIdType, deviceIdIssuingAgency, containsDINumber, pkgQuantity, pkgDiscontinueDate, pkgStatus, pkgType, brandName, versionModelNumber, catalogNumber, dunsNumber, companyName, deviceCount, deviceDescription, DMExempt, premarketExempt, deviceHCTP, deviceKit, deviceCombinationProduct, singleUse, lotBatch, serialNumber, manufacturingDate, expirationDate, donationIdNumber, labeledContainsNRL, labeledNoNRL, MRISafetyStatus, rx, otc, phone, phoneExtension, email, gmdnPTName, gmdnPTDefinition, productCode, productCodeName, deviceSterile, sterilizationPriorToUse)
SELECT
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicDeviceRecordKey').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicVersionStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceRecordStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicVersionDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicPublishDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicCommDistributionEndDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('publicCommDistributionStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/deviceId').value('.', 'VARCHAR(150)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/deviceIdType').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/deviceIdIssuingAgency').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/containsDINumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/pkgQuantity').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/pkgDiscontinueDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/pkgStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('identifiers/identifier/pkgType').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('brandName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('versionModelNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(300)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('catalogNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('dunsNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('companyName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(300)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceCount').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceDescription').value('.', 'VARCHAR(300)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('DMExempt').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('premarketExempt').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceHCTP').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceKit').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('deviceCombinationProduct').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('singleUse').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('lotBatch').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('serialNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('manufacturingDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('expirationDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('donationIdNumber').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('labeledContainsNRL').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('labeledNoNRL').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('MRISafteyStatus').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('rx').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('otc').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('contacts/customerContact/phone').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('contacts/customerContact/phoneExtension').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('contacts/customerContact/email').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('gmdnTerms/gmdn/gmdnPTName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('gmdnTerms/gmdn/gmdnPTDefinition').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('productCodes/fdaProductCode/productCode').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('productCodes/fdaProductCode/productCodeName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('sterilization/deviceSterile').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    MY_XML.Customer.query('sterilization/sterilizationPriorToUse').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM
    (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
     FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\testing.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
CROSS APPLY 
    MY_XML.nodes('device') AS MY_XML (Customer);`
```

Comment: Sample data (XML) and expected results will help us help you

Comment: Thanks Lamu

My current code is attached. I only need the values for:
identifiers/identifier/deviceId
deviceDescription

Which is in every item of the xml list.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the XQuery into the value() function and dropping the query() function.  The XQuery will need to be updated to insure only one value is returned via a "[1]" even if there is never more than 1 value.  If the value is not present, then value() will return null.  As it is, calling value() on a null query() result might be the issue.

BTW, if there can be more than 1 value, you have to decide if you need the data.  If so, then it will be different.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

I don't use XML often, so it takes me about a 100 tries to get the syntax and paths right.  Here's my WAG for the first line of your select.

MY_XML.Customer.value('(./publicDeviceRecordKey)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') as [publicDeviceRecordKey]